# Two way communication between devices

Tags: android, tcp, server, network-programming, kotlin

So I am experiencing a weird issue when trying to communicate over TCP with my two tablets and an external Wifi enabled device.

I will try to describe the issue the best I can. The system works as follows (all communication is conducted over a wireless network):

- the *device* sends a TCP communication to **tablet A**
- **tablet A** (*master*) displays the message and repeats the message to **tablet B** (*slave*) - this works fine
- **tablet A** sends another message (an *action* message) to **tablet B**, which the **tablet B** receives without problems
- when **tablet B** performs an action it sends an *action* message to **tablet A** - here is the problem, the message **does not** get consumed even though it is sent. If I move to another `activity` and return to the previous, the message **is** consumed

This happens with Lenovo YT3 tablets running Android 6.0.1

`SocketListenerService`

```
private var thread: Thread? = null
private var socketListener: SocketListener? = null
private var broadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager? = null
val listener = object : SimpleServer.ServerReceivedListener {

    override fun onLineReceived(line: String) {

        val response = Intent(SOCKET_RESPONSE)
        response.putExtra(RESPONSE_MESSAGE, line)

        broadcastManager!!.sendBroadcast(response)

    }

}

private val incomingServer = SimpleServer(listener)

override fun onCreate() {

    super.onCreate()

    broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)

}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    if (intent != null) {

        socketListener = SocketListener()
        thread = Thread(socketListener)
        thread!!.start()

    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

}

override fun onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy()

    socketListener!!.shutDown()
    thread!!.interrupt()
    incomingServer.closeServer()

}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {

    return null

}

private inner class SocketListener : Runnable {

    @Volatile private var done = false

    internal fun shutDown() {

        done = true

    }

    override fun run() {

        while (!done) {

            incomingServer.serve()

        }

    }

}

companion object {

    val SOCKET_RESPONSE = "socket_response"
    val RESPONSE_MESSAGE = "response_message"

    val port = 9888

}
```

`SimpleServer`

```
interface ServerReceivedListener {

    fun onLineReceived(line: String)

}

private var server: ServerSocket? = null
private var client: Socket? = null
private var listener: ServerReceivedListener? = null

init {

    try {

        server = ServerSocket(SocketListenerService.port)
        this.listener = listener

    } catch (err: Exception) {

        err.printStackTrace()

    }

}

fun serve() {

    var line: String?

    try {

        if (!server!!.isClosed) {

            client = server?.accept()

            val r = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client!!.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))
            line = r.readLine()

            while (line != null) {

                if (line.length >= 4)
                    listener!!.onLineReceived(line)
                else
                    listener!!.onLineReceived("@")
                line = r.readLine()

            }

        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        if (!e.message!!.contains("Socket closed"))
            e.printStackTrace()

    }

}

fun closeServer() {

    try {

        if (client != null)
            client!!.close()
        server!!.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        e.printStackTrace()

    }

}
```

The `BroadcastBeceiver` in turn gets the message from the intent and uses an interface to send it to an `activity`

I just can't seem to understand why the communication from the *slave* only gets consumet by the *master* when the consuming `activity` is restarted(?)

Answer (score 0):

It was a socket issue. Now I have two threads listening on two ports and the communication works fine